# Why is this returning an empty string?

Tags: javascript

I would like this to return s1 and s1 combined together, only the unique characters sorted in a new string called sortedString.  Instead I get an empty string output.

ex input and output:

```
a = "xyaabbbccccdefww"
b = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq"
longest(a, b) -> "abcdefklmopqwxy"  

function longest(s1, s2) {
  var sortedString = '';
  var a = s1.split();
  var b = s2.split();
  for (i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (!sortedString.includes(a[i])) {
      sortedString.concat(a[i]);
      }
  }
  for (j=0; j < b.length; j++) {
    if (!sortedString.includes(b[j])) {
      sortedString.concat(b[j]);
      }
  }
  return sortedString.sort();
}
```

Comment: `i < 10,000` - what is this supposed to do exactly? the comma has meaning in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: besides, string in js doesn't have `sort` method

Comment: O nice catch I removed the comma, same problem though.

Comment: please add some input data and the exected output as well. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: sort method is for array and not string

Comment: Ok, I can remove sort, thanks.  Still the main issue persists though

Comment: As already mentioned in the answers below, you are using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) wrong - did you really debug this code before you posted it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript String type is immutable and concat method don't mutate input so when you type:

```
  sortedString.concat(b[j]);
```

sortedString is never muted. You should make this instead :

`sortedString = sortedString.concat(b[j]);`

Comment: O i think this is what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Comment: :) technically, the opposite of 'immutable' is 'changed', but I kind of like your usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an empty string to `split` if you want to separate the string into a list of characters.

However, I would strongly recommend you solve this declaratively:

```
const allChars = s1.split('').concat(s2.split(''));
return allChars
  .filter((char) => allChars.indexOf(char) === allChars.lastIndexOf(char))
  .sort()
  .join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "xyaabbbccccdefww";
var b = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq";
var mySet = new Set(a.split("").concat(b.split("")));
var result = Array.from(mySet).sort().join("");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for splitting the string and for populating an array.

```js
var a = "xyaabbbccccdefww",
    b = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq",
    result = [...new Set([...(a + b)])].sort().join("");

console.log(result);
```